# Python: Process in one Thread stopping a Process in another Thread from finishing

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, popen, terminate

I'd appreciate some help with threading, which I pretty new to.

The example code is not exactly what I’m doing (‘notepad’ and ‘calc’ are just example commands), but a simplified version that shows my problem.

I want to run two seperate threads that each run a different command a number of times. I would like the code to do this:

1. Start the first instance of ‘notepad’ and ‘calc’ simultaneously
   (which it does)
2. When I close an instance of ‘notepad’, to open the
   next instance of ‘notepad’.
3. When I close an instance of ‘calc’, to
   open the next instance of ‘calc’.
4. [edit] I want the script to wait until both threads have finished, as it needs to do some processing of the output from these.

**However, when I close an instance of ‘notepad’, the next instance of ‘notepad’ does not start until I’ve closed the current instance of ‘calc’ and vice versa.** With a bit of de-bugging, it looks like the process (from Popen) for the closed instance of 'notepad' doesn't finish until the current 'calc' is closed.

Running Python 2.7 on Windows 7

Example Code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from threading import Thread

def do_commands(command_list):

    for command in command_list:
        proc = Popen("cmd.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
        stdout_value, stderr_value = proc.communicate(input=command)

# MAIN CODE
A_command_list = ["notepad\n", "notepad\n", "notepad\n" ]
B_command_list = ["calc\n", "calc\n", "calc\n" ]

A_args = [A_command_list]
B_args = [B_command_list]

A_thread = Thread(target=do_commands, args=(A_args))
B_thread = Thread(target=do_commands, args=(B_args))

A_thread.start()
B_thread.start()

A_thread.join()
B_thread.join()
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Nick

Comment: instead of using `Popen` and `communicate` to launch a cmd, couldn't you just launch the actual executables? Like `subprocess.call(['notepad.exe'])`? (I don't have Windows so you'll have to find the exact name you have to use).

Comment: @Bakuriu - thanks for the input. I considered using call, but I need the stdout and stderr and the documentation says "Note Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function as that can deadlock based on the child process output volume. Use Popen with the communicate() method when you need pipes."

Comment: @NickFromage If you need stdout you may want to use [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). Is basically `call`+`stdout=PIPE` that uses `communicate` to obtain the output.

Comment: @Bakuriu - Thanks. I've tried it with check_output instead of Popen/communicate. It runs the same, but also has the same problem (needs the 'sleep' command to stop it waiting for both processes to end). check_output does seem a bit neater, so I'll try using it in future. :-)

Comment: I don't really understand why that `sleep` hack is needed. If I have time I'll try to think about that. In any case I believe that what `sleep` is doing is simply triggering the scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `communicate()` method is apparently waiting for all processes created by `Popen` and executing `cmd.exe` **and started at nearly the same time** to terminate. Since the `cmd.exe` that runs `calculator` starts at nearly the same time as the `cmd.exe` that runs `Notepad`, both `communicate()` calls (one in `A_thread` and one in `B_thread`) wait until both processes term. Thus neither `for` loop advances until both processes term.

Adding a delay between starting the two threads fixes the problem.

So, leaving your original code unchanged and adding

```
sleep(1)
```

between the two `Thread` `starts` produces the desired behavior.

On my system, adding a delay of 0.0001 seconds reliably fixed the problem whereas a delay of 0.00001 did not.

Comment: The "sleep(1)" seems to work.Thanks very much for your help :-)